# How does NGINX (as a proxy) handle read/write race conditions?

Tags: http, nginx, caching, proxy

I'm using nginx as a proxy cache and I'm worried about race conditions.

How does nginx handle a simultaneous GET and PUT to the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you are asking here. GET, PUT, DELETE, whatever the verb might be, nginx will just call the script and return the response. I am not sure what race conditions are you referring to. nginx can serve thousands of requests in parallel, due to it's [design](https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/)

Comment: To clarify my question. I'm asking if nginx blocks io on a file descriptor when writing or reading a file. According to the co-founder's blog: https://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html, it looks like nginx does block io.

Comment: Here's [another](https://www.nginx.com/blog/thread-pools-boost-performance-9x/) interesting topic on the topic. It talks about threads, AIO, etc. Also, what's your use case? What files are we talking about here? If your OS is modern, a request will put that file in the OS buffer cache, so lots of reads won't even touch the file. I guess it all depends on what workload you are asking and what files are we talking about. Nonetheless, nginx is your best bet for any massive workloads

Comment: And if you are talking about static content, then just a quick example: Cloudflare and biggest CDN's in the world are using nginx. Modified a bit, of course, but the core is nginx.